# Dynamically added javascript to do immediate execution

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm dynamically adding script to the page using DOM.

1. If I add script text (e.g. `script.text = "...";`) it runs immediately.
2. But, if I add an external script (e.g. `script.src = "...";`) it'll run after my script finishes.

So in example below I'll get

> "0 1 2"

and

> "3 3 3"

respectively.

( 1.js contains same string - `"document.body.innerHTML += i"` )

```
<body>
  <script>
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = "1.js";
      //  script.text = "document.body.innerHTML += i";
      document.body.append(script);
    };
  </script>
</body>
```

I do not understand why it works this way, and how do I run 1.js immediately after adding?

Comment: why are you appending same js (**"1.js"**) again and again in body

Comment: @SourabhSomani 'cause I want it to run again and again with different parameters

Comment: Apart from that; why loading a script with different parameters instead of utilizing a function with arguments?

Comment: @lynx 'cause I **have to** use an external script which I don't have access to, just can adjust arguments which that script uses

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic loading of external scripts are queued in order they are requested through browser. It means they are not executed immediately after being downloaded.

W3 HTML5 spec [Scripting](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html) section:

> **If the element has a [src](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-src) attribute, does not have an [async](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-async) attribute,
> and does not have the ["force-async"](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#force-async) flag set**
>
> The element must be added  to the end of the **list of scripts that will execute in order as soon as possible** associated with the [Document](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#document) of the script [element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) at the time [the prepare a script](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#prepare-a-script) algorithm started.

Comment: It answers my 1st question - "Why it works this way". But 2nd and more important - "How do I (Is there a way to) force an external script to run immediately?"

Answer (score 1):

After trying many times, I think it's related to parse of the browser.when you add `script` dynamically, if `src` is specified, its content won't be loaded and ran immediately.the runtime of its content is different with the browser

Following code is running in chrome, firefox, and IE8:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    var script = document.createElement('script')
    script.src = './test.js'  //test.js   alert(2)
    document.body.appendChild(script)
    alert(3)
</script>
<script>
  alert(8)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**The result:**

In IE8, Firefox, the sequence of `alert` is `3 2 8`

IN Chrome, the sequence of `alert` is `3 8 2`

**The conclusion:**

In IE8 and Firefox,

the content of you add `script` dynamically will be running after the current script run completely.

In Chrome,

the content of you add `script` dynamically will be running after the other contents are loaded.